# What happens when you grow claws while wearing cursed gloves?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

In Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup, what happens when you grow claws while you wear cursed gloves?

Comment: If I had to take a guess, the gloves just fall off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your claw mutation reaches level 3 (*You have claws for hands.*), then any gloves are forcibly removed, regardless of whether they are cursed or not.

The same thing happens with boots and the talon / hooves mutations, as well as helmets and the horns, antennae and beak mutations.

The relevant source code calls a function in the transformation code path used for melding items into your body.  That code does not bother to check the cursed status of an item.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had this happen with gloves, but I once grew hooves while wearing cursed boots, and they dropped off. Presumably the same thing will happen with gloves.